# pygame - error object not callable

Tags: python, class, pygame, typeerror

The code I'm having problems with is below. Can someone help me figure out how to fix this error? I'm trying to make is so that when I click start game, it calls the line in main() under the if statement.

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/untitled/Game.py", line 122, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/untitled/Game.py", line 75, in main
    controller = Manager(screen)
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/untitled/Game.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.go_to(TitleMenu(screen))
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/untitled/Game.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.main_loop()
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/untitled/Game.py", line 54, in main_loop
    self.menu.update(events)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled\menumaker.py", line 46, in update
    self.options[self.option][1]()
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/untitled/Game.py", line 38, in <lambda>
    self.menu = makeMenu(["START GAME", lambda: run()], ["CONTROLS", lambda: Help(screen)], ["QUIT GAME", sys.exit])
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

Code:

```
class Manager(object):
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.go_to(TitleMenu(screen))

    def go_to(self, scene):
        self.scene = scene
        self.scene.manager = self
#////////////////End Manager//////////////#
def run():
    global run
    run = True
    pass

#////////////////Title Menu and End Menu//////////////#
class TitleMenu(object):
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.menu = makeMenu(["START GAME", lambda: run()], ["CONTROLS", lambda: Help(screen)], ["QUIT GAME", sys.exit])
        self.menu.set_highlight_color((255, 0, 0))
        self.menu.set_normal_color((255, 255, 255))
        self.menu.center_at(300, 400)
        self.titleBackground = pygame.image.load("titleBackground.png")
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        events = pygame.event.get()
        self.menu.update(events)
        self.menu.draw(self.screen)
        self.main_loop()
        self.run = False

    def main_loop(self):
        while 1:
            self.clock.tick(60)
            events = pygame.event.get()
            self.menu.update(events)
            for e in events:
                if e.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    return

            self.menu.draw(self.screen)
            pygame.display.flip()

    def go_(self):
        self.manager.go_to(GameLevel(0))

class EndMenu(object):
    pass
#////////////////End Title Menu and End Menu//////////#

def main():
    globals()
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
    pygame.display.set_caption("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    controller = Manager(screen)
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()
    running = True

    while running:
        timer.tick(60)
        if pygame.event.get(QUIT):
            running = False
            return

        controller.scene.handle_events(pygame.event.get())
        controller.scene.update()
        controller.scene.render(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

        if run:
            controller.scene.go_()

    return Rect(left, bottom, width, height)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your global variable `run` is getting confused with the `run` function:

```
def run():
    global run
    run = True
    pass
```

This means when you try to call `run()`:

```
    self.menu = makeMenu(["START GAME", lambda: run()], ["CONTROLS", lambda: Help(screen)], ["QUIT GAME", sys.exit])
```

it tries to call the boolean variable. To fix it, rename the global variable `is_running`, or rename the function `start_running`.

Comment: ok that fixed the error but now when I run it nothing happens it just sits there instead of running the function, and when I quit I get an error saying "video system not initialized"

Comment: @user1758231: That sounds like a completely unrelated error. You should try debugging it, and if you can't figure it out you can open a new question. (But just in case- what does your new `run` function look like, and the new `makeMenu` line?)